# git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com locked file error

Tags: linux, git

```
abdullah@XPS:~/Documents/repos/first_app$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
error: could not lock config file /home/abdullah/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I have tried `mkdir .gitconfig`, it states it is already there.
When I try to access any .file it says no such file even though it is right there.

[image: picture of terminal]

Comment: It’s a symlink to something that doesn’t exist. Look in `dotfiles/config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global .gitconfig file is a symlink to a .gitconfig in your Downloads folder. Perhaps the file isn't available anymore?

Regardless, I'd suggest removing the symlink and creating a new .gitconfig file:

```
rm ~/.gitconfig
touch ~/.gitconfig
```

You should then be able to run your command:

```
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```